# NavigationLink inside a VStack is broken on iPad

Tags: swiftui

Consider this very simple view: just a few links to other pages. If you run this on iPhone, everything works as expected. However, run this on the iPad in landscape, and you will notice that most of the time the links simply don't work. Broken in the sim and real device, which is surprising.

When you change the `VStack` to a `List`, everything works fine all of a sudden.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 1")) {
          Text("Link 1")
            .padding(.vertical)
        }

        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 2")) {
          Text("Link 2")
            .padding(.vertical)
        }

        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 3")) {
          Text("Link 3")
            .padding(.vertical)
        }

        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 4")) {
          Text("Link 4")
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
        NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 5")) {
          Text("Link 5")
            .padding(.vertical)
        }
      }

      Text("Hello iPad")
    }
  }
}
```

Has anyone else run into this problem? Why does it happen, and what is the workaround? Other than the obvious "use a List" :p I am using a grid of `VStack`s and `HStack`s to show links in multiple columns, configurable per device size. So changing to a `List` would not be preferable if not 100% necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var showLink1 = false
  // .. and the other 4

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      ZStack {
        List {
          NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 1"), isActive: $showLink1) {
            EmptyView()
          }
          // .. and the other 4
        }
        .opacity(0)

        VStack {
          Button(action: { self.showLink1 = true  }) {
            Text("Link 1")
              .padding(.vertical)
          }
          // .. and the other 4
        }
      }

      Text("Hello iPad")
    }
  }
}
```

Oh, SwiftUI...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to **read the documentation**, before you try to find some "workaround"

```
 // Creates an instance that presents `destination` when `selection` is set
 // to `tag`.
    public init<V>(destination: Destination, tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) where V : Hashable
```

example usage

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Int? = 0
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 0"), tag: 0, selection: $selection) {
                    Text("link 0")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 1"), tag: 1, selection: $selection) {
                    Text("link 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Link 2"), tag: 2, selection: $selection) {
                    Text("link 2")
                }

            }

            Text("Hello iPad user, swipe from left to continue ...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @KevinRenskers this isn't any workaround, this is how Apple intent to use it ... If you feel, that I am aggressive, I apologize. I agree, there is a lack of documentation, use  "Jump to definition" while ctrl-click in xcode. It is the best we have till now

Comment: I'm sorry to say that your code actually doesn't work as expected on iPhone: if you first open link 1, and then link 2, it immediately pops back to the list. My workaround, while a lot more code, works fine in iPhone and iPad. I'm (sadly) going to stick with that for now.

Comment: there is known bug on simulator, it works on device as expected.

Comment: @KevinRenskers check it on device! there is known bug on current simulator, it works on device, as it has to work.

Comment: It does indeed work on device, but since I do most of my development using the simulator, it's really killing productivity. Let's all hope these kinds of bugs will be solved by Apple asap :)

Comment: it seem to be already solved in next release of Xcode (I didn't checked it personally)

Comment: Yeah but that beta has a lot of even worse problems :(